# Installation of a specific version from svn repository

Tags: svn, 8051, contiki, cc, sdcc

I am trying to install a specific revision (9092) of SDCC (on Ubuntu of course), when I run the following command, I get this error:

```
svn: E000110: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/sdcc/code/trunk/sdcc'
svn: E000110: Can't connect to host 'svn.code.sf.net': Connection timed out
```

By the way, i run the following command on Terminal to install it:

```
svn co -r 9092 svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/sdcc/code/trunk/sdcc
```

I am following the instructions as given in this [link.](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/8051-Requirements#build-your-toolchain-sdcc) Can somebody help me install this, please!

Also, how can i check the revision number of SDCC on Ubuntu repository? Is there any manual way to download the repository from that link(svn.code.sf.net/p/sdcc/code/trunk/sdcc) and install it or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn co -r 9092 svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/sdcc/code/trunk/sdcc` works fine for me. Maybe a temporary error.

Comment: It is working for me also now, but I have already installed the current version: 9262. Anyway, that is working fine so far.. do i specifically need that version for working with 8051 based mcu's? (I am working with cc2530)